# How to write from Apache Flink to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to connect Flink to Elasticsearch and when I run the Maven project I have this error :

[image]

or another way to do it, I am using this example : https://github.com/keiraqz/KafkaFlinkElastic

Comment: this is the error :https://image.ibb.co/d6JbCc/error.png

Comment: Please paste the error message in your question.

Comment: Are you set on using Flink? If you want Kafka->Elasticsearch you could just use Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka) and the Elasticsearch connector.

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked depends on various Flink modules with different version which is highly discouraged. Try setting them all to one version and see if this fixes the issue.